# "A field or property with the name 'userdetailsrowid_in' was not found on the selected data source." while binding data to Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

My browser return the error above while im going to load screen for my transaction screen.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conStr);
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand sqlcmm1 = new SqlCommand(" select td.rowid_in, ad.artname_vc,td.purchasedate_dt, td.purchaseamt_nu, td.purchaseunit_in "+
                                        " from transactionDetails td "+
                                        " join userDetails ud " +
                                        " on ud.rowid_in = td.userdetailsrowid_in " +
                                        " join artworkDetails ad " +
                                        " on ad.rowid_in = td.artworkdetailsrowid_in " +
                                        " where ud.userid_vc = @userid_vc", con);
    sqlcmm1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@userid_vc", Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString["UserID"].ToString()));
    SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmm1);
    DataSet ds = new DataSet();
    sda.Fill(ds);
    GridView1.DataSource = ds;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    con.Close();
}
```

and the sql are working fine, but some how the error show while i want to load the screen.

Comment: Maybe your Gridview has a field named "userdetailsrowid_in".May you change `select td.rowid_in` to `select td.rowid_in as userdetailsrowid_in`?

Comment: @MuzafferGALATA yes you are correct it's working now  thank you sir